# Semantics of the outflux argument --output-conn

Tags: influxdb, timescaledb

I'm trying to migrate an InfluxDB database to TimescaleDB with the help of `outflux`:

```
$ outflux migrate database --input-server https://xxx:443 --input-user xxx --input-pass xxx --output-conn "dbname=tutorial user=postgres"
2019/10/18 17:06:42 All pipelines scheduled
2019/10/18 17:06:42 All pipelines finished
2019/10/18 17:06:42 Migration execution time: 0.000 seconds
$
```

As the execution of the command above does not ask for the PostgreSQL password, `outflux` obviously does not connect to PostgreSQL.

But why it does not return an appropriate error message?

How can I properly set the host, port, database, user and password of my PostgreSQL database so that `outflux` connects to it?

Comment: You can set the connection string for timescale with a URI or DSN format, or use env vars. Check out the readme section (https://github.com/timescale/outflux#timescaledb-connection-params) in the string you can specify your password. But it is strange that you did not get any error message. Can you tell me which version of outflux you're using?

Comment: @BlagojAtanasovski Thx, it helped. `Outflux version 0.2.0`